# ui-router display error page without ui-view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router with ui-view in my index.html page. I have defined states and all routes are working properly. Now I want to display an error page without showing header/Footer from index.html. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can defined like this:

```
.when('/error-page/', {templateUrl: 'app/error.template.html', controller: ErrorCtrl})
.otherwise({redirectTo: '/error-page/'});
```

Comment: @user3500670, you can upload your test code on plnkr If you can. It's good way somebody can debug it and help you.